# How can I relate a cellular towers CID with it PCI

Tags: geolocation, iot, cellular-network, lte, nb-iot

I am using the simcom7080g to attempt to triangulate my device location, by running the command +CENG I get the following results:

0: earfcn, pci, rsrp, rssi, rsrq, sinr , lac, cellid mcc, mnc, networkType

1: earfcn, pci, rsrp, rssi, rsrq, sinr

2: earfcn, pci, rsrp, rssi, rsrq, sinr

Cell 0 is the tower I establish communication with and tower 1 and 2 are neighboring towers.

My current workflow is as it follows:

1. Fetch tower 0 information using openCellID api
2. Use towers 0 returned lat,long and range to create a geogrid and fetch nearby towers
3. Filter returned towers by LTE technology, mcc and mnc
4. (Trying to figure out) Use nearby CENG tower information to link to filtered nearby towers list
5. Enrich CENG data and call triangulation api which requires nearby towers PCI.

My question is at follows:

How can I link the CENG information to the openCellID data, specifically after filtering PCI with CID?

Are there any know paid or free libraries to access this information?

How do low energy cellular electronics perform a network scan without having to connect to each tower and triangulate its location?